# Tilde in front of .box-shadow value

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I was looking at bootsrap mixins.less and noticed a tilde in front of box-shadow value. What purpose does it serve? If my website supports IE9 and higher should I be using it?

```
.box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px @{color-rgba}");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the **tilde-quote** CSS [escaping](http://lesscss.org/#escaping).

> In LESS, a tilde `~` before a string `""` literal outputs the string
>   as-is, because it may be a syntax error in pure LESS.

In [this particular instance](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/82e2f87363d960b647bc1e97bf53bbb229b0e703/less/mixins/forms.less#L56), it's used in order to **escape the comma** `,` character at the string which belongs to the **multiple values** of `box-shadow` property.

Because the comma is used to **separate the arguments** of less mixins. So they did:

```css
.foo {
  .box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px @{color-rgba}");
}
```

---

Alternatively, they could pass a **list** of values into the `.box-shadow()` mixin.

From the **[doc](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters)**:

> if the compiler sees at least one semicolon inside mixin call or
>   declaration, it assumes that arguments are separated by semicolons and
>   all commas belong to css lists
>   ...
>   use dummy **semicolon** to create mixin call with one argument containing
>   comma separated css **list**: `.name(1, 2, 3;)`

Hence, they could just use a semicolon at the end of the value to make the compiler treat that as a list:

```
.bar {
  .box-shadow(
    inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px @color-rgba;
                  //  They could append a semicolon here ^
  );
}
```

Which is as the same as:

```
.bar {
  @list: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px @color-rgba;
  .box-shadow(@list);
}
```

Here is **[an example](http://jsbin.com/nolem/1/edit)** of the above approaches.